# Using jquery to check a rails object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I wan't jquery to do something once a certain item is checked.  But the item may not necessarily be there, if it's not then it doesn't do anything.

This is where the checkbox is rendered:

```
.row
          .col-lg-2
            %input{:type => "checkbox", :id => "switchName#{index}", :class => "check", :name => "switchName#{index}", "data-cost-per-unit" => product.cost_in_cents}/
            %label{:for => "switchName#{index}"}
          .col-lg-8
            = hidden_field_tag("order_products[][product_id]", product.id)
            = product.name
            %br
            .subheader= number_to_currency(product.cost_in_cents.to_f / 100)

          .col-lg-2
            -if product.product_type == "Subscription Based"
            -else
              = select_tag("order_products[][quanity]", options_for_select([0,1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]), "data-cost-per-unit" => product.cost_in_cents, id: product.name, class: "drop", :prodindex => index)
```

So basically I want it to render something into a class thats not shown, IF the `product.product_type == "Subscription Based"` and Is currently checked.

Comment: what this means `render something into a class thats not shown`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you meant:

```
        -if product.product_type != "Subscription Based"
          = select_tag("order_products[][quanity]", options_for_select([0,1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]), "data-cost-per-unit" => product.cost_in_cents, id: product.name, class: "drop", :prodindex => index)
```

But this will be equivalent to what you have, and will save you an `else` statement